# Parent Window Slows down a lot on using SetParent through JNA Java

Tags: java, swing, winapi, jna

I am trying to Embed a Game Window inside Java JFrame using `SetParent`. I am using the following kind of Code using Java JNA User32 library.

```
SetParent(GameWin,JFrameWin);
SetWindowPosF(GameWin,null,Game_X_pos ,Game_Y_pos+1,0,0,0x0020 | 0x0001 | 0x0008);
```

The above code is working fine and my game window is becoming a part of the JFrame successfully.
But the controls kept in my JFrame like Drop down list and Buttons heavily slow down after doing this process.

- Whenever I am clicking any button or dropdown list in my JFrame, it is responding after a lot of time something like after 1 or 2 minutes.
- If I don't Embed my game window inside JFrame then everything works fine as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a window from one process be parented by a window of another process you are attaching the message queues of those windows.

The game window likely has a message loop that is quite different from a normal GUI app. Almost certainly this game is not very interested in dispatching your window's queued messages in a timely fashion. The game did not expect to be hijacked in this way.

There's probably not much that you can do to ameliorate this situation. Cross process parenting is something that basically should not be done. More reading on the subject here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx

Comment: Ok, I got it. 
But is there any other alternative way to dock my game window inside JFrame so that it will not slow down my app.

For example: Making game window as child virtually. 
I tried to use AttachThreadInput to share the focus between parent and child window,But it doesn't worked out. 

So, if you can suggest some alternative way to dock the Game window inside JFrame, it would be good.

Comment: I don't think that there can be a good way to do this without cooperation from the other process. Why don't you talk to the game developer and work together on this?

Comment: I myself is the Game Developer. I Developed the game in Unity 3D and created a Unity3D build executable. That executable window I want to dock inside JFrame. The Java and Unity Application are communicating through local socket connection.

Comment: So I guess you are in a good place. You need to understand both message loops. Probably just need mods to the game's message loop.